# php syntax easy questions

Tags: php, variables, syntax

I know its just syntax but i need some fresh eyes.

Code:

```
$module = $row['module'];
$item = $row['item'];
$return .= '<li '.$liClass.'><a ' . $aHrefAttr . ' href="index.php?module={$module}&item={$item}">'.$row['caption'].'</a>';
```

Link that i get: `index.php?module={$module}&item={$item}`.

So basically it should insert the values

Comment: what's  your problem?

Comment: in actual html link (href) i get index.php?module={$module}&item={$item}. Instead i should get values of these variables.

Comment: Break out of the quotes and concatenate with `.` like you did with other vars.

Answer (score 1):

@AbraCadaver was correct. Should be like this:

```
$return .= '<li '.$liClass.'><a ' . $aHrefAttr . ' href="index.php?module='.$module.'&item='.$item.'">'.$row['caption'].'</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
If you are using {} for concatenation then you are wrong. In PHP use **.** for this.

```
$module = $row['module'];
$item = $row['item'];
$return .= '<li '.$liClass.'><a ' . $aHrefAttr . ' href="index.php?module={'.$module.'}&item={'.$item.'}">'.$row['caption'].'</a>';



$return .= '<li '.$liClass.'><a ' . $aHrefAttr . ' href="index.php?module='.$module.'&item='.$item.'">'.$row['caption'].'</a>';
```

Comment: Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Do or do not. There is not try. ~ Master Yoda

Comment: @JohnConde Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Do it like this:

````
$module = $row['module'];
$item = $row['item'];
$return .= '<li '.$liClass.'><a ' . $aHrefAttr . ' href="index.php?module=' . $module . '&item=' . $item . '">'.$row['caption'].'</a>';```
````

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.